# Which datatype and size for text with n characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, varchar, nvarchar

I'm having trouble understanding how to define a column for my text that has the right size for my max. number of characters. In Oracle I can create a `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)` which will be big enough for 10 characters. The size depends on the encoding used in the database. But how do I do that in SQL Server? Do I use `varchar(10)`? `nvarchar(10)`? I want to be able to store all kinds of characters (even chinese).

Comment: I don't really think it's a duplicate, because I still doesn't tell how large my datatype has to be for a number of n characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Chinese characters, you need to use `nvarchar(n)` and specify a length of `n` that makes sense.

Those are **characters** you're defining, and the space you need is twice that number (since any Unicode character in SQL Server always uses 2 bytes).

Max. size is `nvarchar(4000)` - or if you really need more, use `nvarchar(max)` (for up to **1 billion** characters).

I would recommend **NOT** to just use `nvarchar(max)` for everything, out of lazyness about considering what size you really need! Since it's a really large column, you won't be able to index it for one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `nvarchar(max)` this will allow for any number of characters for all character sets. The system will optimise storage.

Limitations on row size are addressed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx). See answer from @marc_s for limitations on the use of `max`.

Comment: And this won't cause any problem if I create a large number of columns?

Comment: You won't be able to **index** such a column - I would recommend ***NOT*** to just use  `nvarchar(max)` for everything, out of lazyness to think about what size you **really** need - use `nvarchar` for Unicode characters - but choose a **meaningful, useful** length !

Comment: But that's why I'm asking here. What would a meaningful length for 10 chinese characters be? Would that be a nvarchar(10)?

Comment: Yes, `nvarchar(10)` for 10 Chinese characters.